# Angular 2 disable form button from ts?

Tags: angular

Using the Angular 2 Validators, if the form is invalid, the form button is disabled from the HTML itself like so:

```
<button class="btn btn-info" [disabled]="!signupForm.valid">Sign Up</button>
```

How would I use this same effect in the appropriate TS? For instance:

```
youshallnotpass(){ !this.signupForm.valid; }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using template driven forms, you could get a hold of the it using `ViewChild`. Here's something you can do:

Considering:

```
<form ... #myForm="ngForm">
```

You could, at the TypeScript component code:

```
import { ViewChild, NgForm } from '@angular/core';
...
export class MyFormComponent {
    ...
    @ViewChild('myForm') public myForm: NgForm;

    youshallnotpass(){ return !this.myForm || !this.myForm.valid; }
    ...
```